# YouTube iframe Embeds: player control overlay stuck due to missing touch-up event

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using the [YouTube iframe player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) inline in an iOS App with a `WkWebView`. When I close the App it sometimes happens that the player control bar at the bottom gets stuck and no longer disappears.

This seems to happen whenever I tab and hold on the player and then close the app without lifting my finger (this can be triggered accidentally by the swipe-up-to-close-app-gesture), I'm assuming this happens due to the touch-up event not happening on the player. Other than killing the App, no amount of taps/swipes afterwards makes the player overlay become unstuck again.

Is there anything I can do to hide the overlay manually or reset something about the js events that would help it get unstuck? Thanks :)

#### Edit: How to reproduce the issue

Visit any page with an embedded YouTube video, such as [this one](https://www.uploadvr.com/between-realities-vr-podcast-ft-kenseigamingvr/). Tap play on the video, tab and hold on the video somewhere, close the browser while still holding down, then open it again. The player overlay controls will stay on and no longer disappear:

[image: example image]

Comment: May be you will show us how it's stuck with photo video?, or share your code

Comment: @DanielHakobyan I've added details on how to reproduce it, it works with any YouTube iframe embed on a touch device.

Comment: Good job, now it will be easier to understand your question and answer it!